# PHP CRC not the same as Java CRC

Tags: java, php, crc16

I'm trying to do CRC16 in PHP and get the same results as I do in Java.

Some criteria for the CRC16

1. polynomial of 8005
2. initial remainder of 0
3. a final XOR value of 0
4. neither input nor output are reflected

In java I pass a 5 byte message containing the values 1,2,3,4,5 and I get the value 0xB059.

JAVA CODE

```
package crc;
public class Crc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      char crc = 0X0000;  
      char temp = 0X0000;   
      char[] data = new char[5];
      data[0]=1;data[1]=2;data[2]=3;data[3]=4;data[4]=5;
      for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
          char value = (char)data[i];

          temp =(char)(value ^(char)(crc >> 8));
          temp =(char)(temp ^(char)(temp >> 4));
          temp =(char)(temp ^(char)(temp >> 2));
          temp =(char)(temp ^(char)(temp >> 1));
          crc = (char)((char)(crc << 8) ^ (char)(temp<<15)^(char)(temp << 2)^temp);
      }
      System.out.println(crc);
    }
}
```

PHP CODE

```
 function crc16($str){
    $crc  = 0X0000;
    $temp = 0X0000;
    $length = strlen($str);

    $data = unpack("C*", $str);
    for($i=0;$i<($length);$i++){
        $value = $data[$i];

        $temp = ($value ^($crc >> 8));
        $temp = ($temp ^($temp >> 4));
        $temp = ($temp ^($temp >> 2));
        $temp = ($temp ^($temp >> 1));
        $crc  = (($crc << 8) ^ ($temp<<15)^($temp << 2)^$temp);

    }
    return $crc;
 }

  echo crc16("\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05");
```

Took this code and converted it to PHP and no luck.If anyone has any direction to help that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your PHP version? And what does "no luck" mean? What were the differences? Were there errors?

Comment: php:5.5 and no luck means I didn't get the same results as in java.

Then I searched the web and just tried one after another phpcrc16 scripts that i could find.

Comment: I meant, where is your PHP source code, sorry.

Comment: Please add it to your question... The comment section is not a place for code as it is completely unreadable.

Comment: Sorry new to this. its added to question

Comment: One thing that jumps straight to the eye is that you are taking `strlen($length)`. You probably wanted to just  do `$i < $length`. Also, your input is completely different.

Comment: fixed the strlen($length) but what do you mean my inputs are different

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `pack` thing. It's probably `unpack` that you wanted, and then the equivalent of the Java input would be "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05", not "12345". I don't know where you got that Java program, but it is abusing the `char` type when it should have used `short`.

Comment: I got it ! Thank you ! Just the fact that i needed to enter the number like you said \x01\x02\x03\x04\x05 instead of 12345